# How sort with sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have db like this :
id, name, group.
(Group is a slug, that I can't know for my request)
So one group can have many name.
I want to sort by group with php/mysql.

I want get something like this :

```
$request = array( 'groupeOne = array ('name')', 'groupeTwo = array()' )
```

Something like this. I try to order by group but it doesn't work

Comment: you can use order by  but with backticks around group (is a reserved  word)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

order by

```
    `group`     (using backtics  ..because group is a reserver word 

 select tid, name, `group`
 from my_table 
 order by `group`
```